# Text editor support for rmarkdown documents

Tags: r, editor, r-markdown

I was a bit surprised that this question hasn't been asked before. (If it has, apologies!) I am trying to find a good text editor with support for `rmarkdown` documents. Here are my criteria (in no particular order):

- syntax highlighting (for both R code and markdown syntax)
- ability to send code from document to console for evaluation
- free & open source
- autocompletion for bibtex entries
- cross-platform

I can't seem to find anything that fits the bill. Sublime Text can do all of this, but it's neither free nor open source...

I know a lot of people use RStudio, but its support for actually writing is not very good at all (e.g. bad spellcheck, no support for navigating a file, etc)...

Comment: https://github.com/DaveJarvis/scrivenvar - let me know if it interests you. See also: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/38157/8633

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to any question involving editors is of course ... Emacs.  In all seriousness:

- [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) for R
- [Polymode](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode) (by one of the ESS authors) for mixed mode
- [markdown](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) mode by Jason Blevins (which is IIRC bundled with recent Emacs versions)

work well for me.  I still go back to latex for 'real' papers with bibtex, but folks do this with markdown too so there will surely be a mode.  And yes, it is cross-platform.

I use these on Ubuntu, and maintain the ESS package for Debian. So that one is always current.  For polymode I just go to Github.  It all works of course with MELPA and Emacs package archives.

Comment: I've looked at Emacs, but from what I've seen online it isn't so great with rmarkdown. And, of course... That learning curve.

Comment: it's way better than rstudio for rmarkdown imo (for everything except rendering anyway).

Comment: Emacs is a rough learning curve and you have to set it all up. It's not convenient, but it is very expert friendly and extensible. It's something you have to be committed to.

Comment: I would say +1 for all of this.  Not sure about bibtex autocompletion, but it's probably out there. I have found polymode to be a *tiny* bit bleeding-edge, but 99.5% stable ...  I like the fact that emacs/polymode is smart about Roxygen stuff too (slightly smarter than RStudio's editor)

Comment: I would downvote any post recommending Emacs on principle if it weren't the rude thing to do :)

Comment: Emacs seems to be the only program that can do everything I want, so I've marked this as the accepted answer and am off to learn this o̶p̶e̶r̶a̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶y̶s̶t̶e̶m̶ editor.

Comment: It is a good investment.  I've been an Emacs user for 20+ years and the extensibility really is key--while providing a consistent interface to _many_ modes.

Answer (score 2):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) is free, extensible, and open source.

The only thing I can't get it to do is R code syntax inside a code chunk of an `Rmd` file (similar to Sublime).

Comment: I'm excited about Atom, but it seems like it has a long way to go. Basically, if someone built an Atom package like the one listed in this thread, I'd be a happy camper. But for now, Atom just doesn't have the capabilities that I'm looking for. https://discuss.atom.io/t/package-suggestion-rmarkdown/15074

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience with Vim, you should check out [Vim-R](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628). I use it exclusively; it sends code to R, and has loads of other awesome features. In terms of syntax highlighting, I don't know if there is any specifically for `rmarkdown`, but there are vim plugins for `markdown`, and the syntax highlighting for R files is quite good with `Vim-R`.

I actually never use markdown in any form, but create `.Rnw` files and use `knitr` to create PDF's (via `pdflatex`). `Vim-R` will also send relevant `knitr` commands; e.g., if you want to **k**nit **p**df, you type (in vim) `\kp`. If you want to run it through `biblatex`, you type `\kb`.

---

EDIT: I'm not sure if there is autocompletion for `bibtex` entries, though. There probably is in `vim-latex`, but of course that isn't `R` related. However, you might be able to install both plugins and incorporate that command for your own uses.